# Modify environment json array variable via docker-compose file

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, docker-compose

I'm trying to modify environment variables of my application via `docker-compose.yml` file.

My `appsettings.Development.json` looks like below:

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=127.0.0.1,1433;Database=app;User Id=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd"
  },
  "EventBusSettings": {
    "HostAddress": "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Roles": [
    "Member",
    "Admin"
  ]
}
```

Using docker-compose.yml I modify `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection` and `EventBusSettings:HostAddress` like in example below:

```yaml
# ...
app:
    image: app
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/App/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - db
      - rabbitmq
      - portainer
    environment:
      - ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection=Server=db,1433;Database=app;User Id=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd
      - EventBusSettings:HostAddress=amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
# ...
```

How can I modify first element of `Roles` in `appsettings.Development.json` via docker-compose.yml?

Comment: Not sure if you can assign a list there, you could try to access first index using Roles[0]=somevalue. 

If this is not possible you could still create a new Dockerfile / Image from your existing one and add your json config at the right place, replacing the existing one you want to overwrite. If you need more flexibility you could use templating in that conf file and replace while building container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do it by setting `Roles__0` to the value you want.

Comment: Can you please extend the exmaple to more details, many thanks